# How to get records count of Shape File with ( .shp extension) in android

Tags: android, shapefile

I am trying to get the count of records in a Shape File.The file is a polygon shape file. I am able to get the details of the first record but when count increments to 2, an IllegalState exception is raised and it gives record count as 0.

My Android Activity class is

```
package com.example.android.skeletonapp;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SkeletonActivity extends Activity {

    static final private int BACK_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    static final private int CLEAR_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private EditText mEditor;
    public SkeletonActivity(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int recordCount = 0;
        // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
        setContentView(R.layout.skeleton_activity);

        // Find the text editor view inside the layout, because we
        // want to do various programmatic things with it.
        mEditor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editor);

        // Hook up button presses to the appropriate event handler.
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.back)).setOnClickListener(mBackListener);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.clear)).setOnClickListener(mClearListener);

        mEditor.setText(getText(R.string.main_label));
        try {

             String shpFile = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/ne_50m_urban_areas.shp";
            ShapeReader shR = new ShapeReader(shpFile, true);
                recordCount = shR.getCount(0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mEditor.setText("Record Count == " + recordCount);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * Called when your activity's options menu needs to be created.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        // We are going to create two menus. Note that we assign them
        // unique integer IDs, labels from our string resources, and
        // given them shortcuts.
        menu.add(0, BACK_ID, 0, R.string.back).setShortcut('0', 'b');
        menu.add(0, CLEAR_ID, 0, R.string.clear).setShortcut('1', 'c');

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Called right before your activity's option menu is displayed.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        // Before showing the menu, we need to decide whether the clear
        // item is enabled depending on whether there is text to clear.
        menu.findItem(CLEAR_ID).setVisible(mEditor.getText().length() > 0);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Called when a menu item is selected.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case BACK_ID:
            finish();
            return true;
        case CLEAR_ID:
            mEditor.setText("");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A call-back for when the user presses the back button.
     */
    OnClickListener mBackListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    };

    /**
     * A call-back for when the user presses the clear button.
     */
    OnClickListener mClearListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mEditor.setText("");
        }
    };
}
```

And ShapeFileReader class is

```
package com.example.android.skeletonapp;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ShapeReader  {
    private static final int UNKNOWN = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public final class Record {
        int length;

        public int number = 0;

        int offset; // Relative to the whole file

        int start = 0; // Relative to the current loaded buffer

        /** The minimum X value. */
        public double minX;

        /** The minimum Y value. */
        public double minY;

        /** The maximum X value. */
        public double maxX;

        /** The maximum Y value. */
        public double maxY;

        public ShapeType type;

        int end = 0; // Relative to the whole file

        Object shape = null;

        /** Fetch the shape stored in this record. */
        public Object shape() {
            if (shape == null) {
                buffer.position(start);
                buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                if (type == ShapeType.NULL) {
                    shape = null;
                } else {
                    shape = handler.read(buffer, type, flatGeometry);
                }
            }
            return shape;
        }

        public int offset() {
            return offset;
        }

        /** A summary of the record. */
        public String toString() {
            return "Record " + number + " length " + length + " bounds " + minX
                    + "," + minY + " " + maxX + "," + maxY;
        }
    }     

    private ShapeHandler handler;

    private ShapefileHeader header;

    private ReadableByteChannel channel;

    ByteBuffer buffer;

    private ShapeType fileShapeType = ShapeType.UNDEFINED;

    private ByteBuffer headerTransfer;

    private final Record record = new Record();

    private final boolean randomAccessEnabled = true;

    private boolean useMemoryMappedBuffer;

    private long currentOffset = 0L;

    private int currentShape = 0;

    //private IndexFile shxReader;

    //private StreamLogging streamLogger = new StreamLogging("Shapefile Reader");

    //private GeometryFactory geometryFactory;

    private boolean flatGeometry;

    public ShapeReader(String shpFile,
            boolean useMemoryMapped) throws IOException  {
        this.channel = new FileInputStream(shpFile).getChannel();
        this.useMemoryMappedBuffer = useMemoryMapped;
        //randomAccessEnabled = channel instanceof FileChannel;
        init(true);
    }

    // ensure the capacity of the buffer is of size by doubling the original
    // capacity until it is big enough
    // this may be naiive and result in out of MemoryError as implemented...
    private ByteBuffer ensureCapacity(ByteBuffer buffer, int size,
            boolean useMemoryMappedBuffer) {
        // This sucks if you accidentally pass is a MemoryMappedBuffer of size
        // 80M
        // like I did while messing around, within moments I had 1 gig of
        // swap...
        if (buffer.isReadOnly() || useMemoryMappedBuffer) {
            return buffer;
        }

        int limit = buffer.limit();
        while (limit < size) {
            limit *= 2;
        }
        if (limit != buffer.limit()) {
            // clean up the old buffer and allocate a new one
            buffer = NIOUtilities.allocate(limit);
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    // for filling a ReadableByteChannel
    public static int fill(ByteBuffer buffer, ReadableByteChannel channel)
            throws IOException {
        int r = buffer.remaining();
        // channel reads return -1 when EOF or other error
        // because they a non-blocking reads, 0 is a valid return value!!
        while (buffer.remaining() > 0 && r != -1) {
            r = channel.read(buffer);
        }
        buffer.limit(buffer.position());
        return r;
    }

    private void init(boolean strict) throws IOException {
        if (channel instanceof FileChannel && useMemoryMappedBuffer) {
            FileChannel fc = (FileChannel) channel;
            buffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
            buffer.position(0);
            this.currentOffset = 0;
        } else {
            // force useMemoryMappedBuffer to false
            this.useMemoryMappedBuffer = false;
            // start small
            buffer = NIOUtilities.allocate(1024);
            fill(buffer, channel);
            buffer.flip();
            this.currentOffset = 0;
        }
        header = new ShapefileHeader();
        header.read(buffer, strict);
        fileShapeType = header.getShapeType();
        //handler = fileShapeType.getShapeHandler(gf);
        //if (handler == null) {
        //    throw new IOException("Unsuported shape type:" + fileShapeType);
        //}

        headerTransfer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
        headerTransfer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

        // make sure the record end is set now...
        record.end = this.toFileOffset(buffer.position());
    }

    /**
     * Get the header. Its parsed in the constructor.
     * 
     * @return The header that is associated with this file.
     */
    public ShapefileHeader getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    // do important cleanup stuff.
    // Closes channel !
    /**
     * Clean up any resources. Closes the channel.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     *                 If errors occur while closing the channel.
     */
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // don't throw NPE on double close
        if(channel == null)
            return;
        try {
            if (channel.isOpen()) {
                channel.close();
                //streamLogger.close();
            }
            NIOUtilities.clean(buffer, useMemoryMappedBuffer);
        } finally {
            //if(shxReader != null)
            //    shxReader.close();
        }
        //shxReader = null;
        channel = null;
        header = null;
    }

    public boolean supportsRandomAccess() {
        return randomAccessEnabled;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() throws IOException {
        return this.hasNext(true);
    }

    private boolean hasNext(boolean checkRecno) throws IOException {
        // don't read past the end of the file (provided currentShape accurately
        // represents the current position)
        if(currentShape > UNKNOWN )
            return true;

        // mark current position
        int position = buffer.position();

        // ensure the proper position, regardless of read or handler behavior
        //buffer.position(getNextOffset());

        // no more data left
        if (buffer.remaining() < 8)
            return false;

        // looks good
        boolean hasNext = true;
        if (checkRecno) {
            // record headers in big endian
            buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
            int declaredRecNo = buffer.getInt();
            hasNext = declaredRecNo == record.number + 1;
        }

        // reset things to as they were
        buffer.position(position);

        return hasNext;
    }

    /*private int getNextOffset() throws IOException {
        if(currentShape >= 0) {
            return this.toBufferOffset(shxReader.getOffsetInBytes(currentShape));
        } else {
            return this.toBufferOffset(record.end);
        }
    }
    */

    /**
     * Fetch the next record information.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     * @return The record instance associated with this reader.
     */
    public Record nextRecord() throws IOException {

        // need to update position
        //buffer.position(getNextOffset());
        if(currentShape != UNKNOWN)
            currentShape++;

        // record header is big endian
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

        // read shape record header
        int recordNumber = buffer.getInt();
        // silly ESRI say contentLength is in 2-byte words
        // and ByteByffer uses bytes.
        // track the record location
        int recordLength = buffer.getInt() * 2;

        if (!buffer.isReadOnly() && !useMemoryMappedBuffer) {
            // capacity is less than required for the record
            // copy the old into the newly allocated
            if (buffer.capacity() < recordLength + 8) {
                this.currentOffset += buffer.position();
                ByteBuffer old = buffer;
                // ensure enough capacity for one more record header
                buffer = ensureCapacity(buffer, recordLength + 8,
                        useMemoryMappedBuffer);
                buffer.put(old);
                NIOUtilities.clean(old, useMemoryMappedBuffer);
                fill(buffer, channel);
                buffer.position(0);
            } else
            // remaining is less than record length
            // compact the remaining data and read again,
            // allowing enough room for one more record header
            if (buffer.remaining() < recordLength + 8) {
                this.currentOffset += buffer.position();
                buffer.compact();
                fill(buffer, channel);
                buffer.position(0);
            }
        }

        // shape record is all little endian
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        // read the type, handlers don't need it
        ShapeType recordType = ShapeType.forID(buffer.getInt());

        // this usually happens if the handler logic is bunk,
        // but bad files could exist as well...
        if (recordType != ShapeType.NULL && recordType != fileShapeType) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ShapeType changed illegally from "
                    + fileShapeType + " to " + recordType);
        }

        // peek at bounds, then reset for handler
        // many handler's may ignore bounds reading, but we don't want to
        // second guess them...
        buffer.mark();
        if (recordType.isMultiPoint()) {
            record.minX = buffer.getDouble();
            record.minY = buffer.getDouble();
            record.maxX = buffer.getDouble();
            record.maxY = buffer.getDouble();
        } else if (recordType != ShapeType.NULL) {
            record.minX = record.maxX = buffer.getDouble();
            record.minY = record.maxY = buffer.getDouble();
        }
        buffer.reset();

        record.offset = record.end;
        // update all the record info.
        record.length = recordLength;
        record.type = recordType;
        record.number = recordNumber;
        // remember, we read one int already...
        record.end = this.toFileOffset(buffer.position()) + recordLength - 4;
        // mark this position for the reader
        record.start = buffer.position();
        // clear any cached shape
        // record.shape = null;

        return record;
    }

    /**
     * Parses the shpfile counting the records.
     * 
     * @return the number of non-null records in the shapefile
     */
    public int getCount(int count) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (channel == null)
                return -1;
            count = 0;
            long offset = this.currentOffset;
            try {
                goTo(100);
            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                return -1;
            }
            while (hasNext()) {
                count++;
                nextRecord();
            }

            goTo((int) offset);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            count = -1;
            // What now? This seems arbitrarily appropriate !
            throw new Exception("Problem reading shapefile record",
                    ioe);
        }
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Moves the reader to the specified byte offset in the file. Mind that:
     * <ul>
     * <li>it's your responsibility to ensure the offset corresponds to the
     * actual beginning of a shape struct</li>
     * <li>once you call this, reading with hasNext/next on sparse shapefiles
     * will be broken (we don't know anymore at which shape we are)</li>
     * </ul>
     * 
     * @param offset
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException
     */
    public void goTo(int offset) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedOperationException {
        if (randomAccessEnabled) {
            if (this.useMemoryMappedBuffer) {
                buffer.position(offset);
            } else {
                /*
                 * Check to see if requested offset is already loaded; ensure
                 * that record header is in the buffer
                 */
                if (this.currentOffset <= offset
                        && this.currentOffset + buffer.limit() >= offset + 8) {
                    buffer.position(this.toBufferOffset(offset));
                } else {
                    FileChannel fc = (FileChannel) this.channel;
                    fc.position(offset);
                    this.currentOffset = offset;
                    buffer.position(0);
                    buffer.limit(buffer.capacity());
                    fill(buffer, fc);
                    buffer.position(0);
                }
            }

            int oldRecordOffset = record.end;
            record.end = offset;
            try {
                hasNext(true); // don't check for next logical record equality
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                record.end = oldRecordOffset;
                throw ioe;
            }
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Random Access not enabled");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converts file offset to buffer offset
     * 
     * @param offset
     *                The offset relative to the whole file
     * @return The offset relative to the current loaded portion of the file
     */
    private int toBufferOffset(int offset) {
        return (int) (offset - this.currentOffset);
    }

    /**
     * Converts buffer offset to file offset
     * 
     * @param offset
     *                The offset relative to the buffer
     * @return The offset relative to the whole file
     */
    private int toFileOffset(int offset) {
        return (int) (this.currentOffset + offset);
    }

    public String id() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }

    public void setFlatGeometry(boolean flatGeometry) {
        this.flatGeometry = flatGeometry;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a well supported library for this requirement.  You can get [Shapelib](http://shapelib.maptools.org/) (component of GDAL/OGR) working with the [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Using shapelib will give you access to [DBFGetRecordCount](http://shapelib.maptools.org/dbf_api.html), which returns the number of records that exist on the xBase file.

I made a [demo](https://github.com/snodnipper/shapelib-android-demo) shapefile writer app, which has the line:

`const int recordCount = DBFGetRecordCount(hDBF);`